# Android studio: Error:Could not download javawriter.jar

Tags: java, android

When i create the android studio project it will always shows and also in every time i created new project it will appear. Please help me to fix this.
I'm using Android Studio of version 2.2.2

Gradle 'MyNewApp' project refresh failed
    Error:Error:Could not download javawriter.jar (com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1): No cached version available for offline mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same problem and resolved by this way.

Step1: Click File/Setting/Build Execution,Development/Gradle then uncheck "Offline work".
[image]

Step2: File/Invalidate Caches and Restart then select "Invalidate Caches and Restart".

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading a new version from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and once installation is done do not select 'import from previous instance'.And also make sure you have the latest JDK installed on your PC.