# Unable to load class 'com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter'

Tags: java, android, firebase

my android project contains Libraries of Firebase, retrofit,and glide. While I am trying to run the application , i get this error.

```
 Unable to load class 'com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

build.gradle(Module)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    buildFeatures {

        dataBinding true

        // for view binding:
        // viewBinding true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.golottery"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}




    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.lukelorusso:CodeEditText:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
}
```

build.gradle(project)

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}




    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I resolve this problem? After searching for an hour, only get this [Android studio: Error:Could not download javawriter.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741848/android-studio-errorcould-not-download-javawriter-jar)  link but it could not work for me.

Comment: You may wish to edit your question and post both `build.gradle` files (the project-level one and the one for your module). You might also consider posting the entire error output from Gradle, as that may give us more clues as to what is trying to use the old JavaWriter library.

Comment: @CommonsWare question is updated.

Comment: Problem is solved by following this link <https://fantashit.com/execution-failed-for-task-app-generatedebugbuildconfig-can-t-run-flutter-app-on-my-mobile/>